# Client-side oauth2 workflow: parameter vs. header

Tags: javascript, authentication, xmlhttprequest, google-api, oauth-2.0

I just want to get this straight.

I'm using oauth2 to authenticate my client-side app (i.e. browser app) agains to google calendar v3 API. Until now I used a string parameter with the `access_token` to call the endpoints.

After I switched to header authentification I noticed that the browser needs two xhr requests to call an endpoint where the first one is OPTIONS and the second the actual GET request. **This is an expected behavior, right?**

Of course, under certain conditions this slows down the user experience. **Is it possible to have only one xhr (GET) request with header authentification?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. When setting a custom header (in this case an auth header) a preflight request is triggered. ([Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0), [Blogpost by Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/))

If you want to save the extra roundtrip call the endpoint with the `access_token` parameter.

If you still see a `OPTION` request, check if your js lib/framework sets a custom header. There was [a (long gone) bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8423) in jQuery for instance.